The closed points of $\mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{R}$ do not correspond to ordered pairs of closed points of $\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{R}$
In Eisenbud & Harris's The Geometry of Schemes, after a discussion of the closed points in $\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{R}$ and in $\mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{R}$, the authors note that

The closed points in $\mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{R}$ do not correspond to ordered pairs of closed points in $\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{R}$.

I feel like I'm missing something simple here, because I don't see how this correspondence fails. Closed points of $\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{R} = \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{R}[x]$ can be identified with the image of $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ or the image of $x$ together with its complex conjugate in $\mathbb{C}$, depending on the residue field. On the other hand, the closed points of $\mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{R} = \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ can be identified similarly, either with a pair of elements in $\mathbb{R}$, or with a pair of pairs $(z, w)$ and $(\overline{z}, \overline{w})$, where at least one of $z$ and $w$ is not in $\mathbb{R}$.
It seems like this describes the ordered pairs of points from $\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{R}$: either we choose two $\mathbb{R}$ points (and order matters since the ideal $(x - \lambda, y - \mu)$ is not equal to the ideal $(y - \lambda, x - \mu)$), or we choose an $\mathbb{R}$ point followed by a $\mathbb{C}$ point (or vice versa), or we choose two $\mathbb{C}$ points.
Clearly I'm missing something simple here, but what are the points that "don't correspond to ordered pairs of closed points in $\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{R}$"?

@QiaochuYuan Wait, I'm also studying algebraic geometry, aren't all closed points just the maxial ideals? After all, a prime ideal's closure contains all bigger ideals.
I thought the reason the correspondance fails is because $\mathbb{R}$ is not algebraically closed.

Ah, sorry, I'm being silly, you're right that this is about $\mathbb{R}$ not being algebraically closed. The point is just that the closed points of $\mathbb{A}^2$ are not in bijection with ordered pairs of closed points of $\mathbb{A}^1$, since an ordered pair of complex points $z, w$ of $\mathbb{A}^1$ corresponds to two different complex points of $\mathbb{A}^1$, namely the orbit of $(z, w)$ and the orbit of $(z, \bar{w})$.

A point of $\mathbb A_{\mathbb R}^1$ is a maximal ideal $\mathfrak m=(f)$ of $\mathbb R[x]$, where $f\in\mathbb R[x]$ is an irreducible polynomial. There are two types of points, depending on whether $\mathbb R[x]/(f)$ is $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$.
Given points $(f)$ and $(g)$ of $\mathbb A_{\mathbb R}^1$, the ring $\mathbb R[x,y]$ has an ideal $(f(x),g(y))$. Here
$$\mathbb R[x,y]/(f(x),g(y))\simeq\mathbb R[x]/(f)\otimes_{\mathbb R}\mathbb R[y]/(g).$$
There are four possibilities for this ring, according to the two types for both $(f)$ and $(g)$:
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb R\otimes\mathbb R&\simeq\mathbb R\\
\mathbb R\otimes\mathbb C&\simeq\mathbb C\\
\mathbb C\otimes\mathbb R&\simeq\mathbb C\\
\mathbb C\otimes\mathbb C&\simeq\mathbb C\times\mathbb C.
\end{align*}$$
The issue is with the last possibility: the two points of $\mathbb A_{\mathbb R}^1$ does not correspond to a single point of $\mathbb A_{\mathbb R}^2$.
Concretely, $\mathbb R[x,y]/(x^2+1,y^2+1)\simeq\mathbb C\times\mathbb C$, so the points $(x^2+1)$ and $(y^2+1)$ of $\mathbb A_{\mathbb R}^1$ correspond to the points $(x^2+1,y^2+1,xy+1)$ and $(x^2+1,y^2+1,xy-1)$ of $\mathbb A_{\mathbb R}^2$.
